# Why did Albus say, "Lily"?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), While speaking to Albus, Snape sends a [magical horse](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Horse)
to Harry Potter, who is at snowy forest:

> Snape: Expecto Patronum.
>
> Albus: **Lily**. After all this time?
>
> Snape: Always.

Why did Albus say, "Lily" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patronus was a doe, not a horse; it was the same as Lily's.

Comment: And Lily's patronus was a doe because she was in love with James Potter, whose animagus form is a stag. So the origin for Snape's patronus is James Potter?